# VSCode Jupyter Notebook syntax highlighting and autocompletion stopped working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

So, I've been using VSCode for Jupyter notebooks for almost a year and a half now, and it always used to work normally, but a couple of days ago it just got broken, and I don't know why. Here's what I mean:

[Jupyter Notebook on VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNa6h.png)

As you can see, there's no syntax highlighting, and autocompletion doesn't work at all... but if I run the code, it does run perfectly.

It works normally in Python scripts though:

[Normal Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqa2Z.png)

Relevant Extensions I've got:

- Jupyter (+ Keymap & Notebook Renderers)
- Python
- Pylance

I've got a bunch of others for C++ and Java.

Also, I've noticed that both Jupyter and Python extensions give an uncaught error, here's what I mean:

[Jupyter Extension Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTNXV.png)
[Python Extension Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX09R.png)

I have no clue what any of this means. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the extensions, re-installing VSCode, resetting settings.json and restarting my laptop, nothing worked.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have installed the extension of `Dependency Analytics`? You need to disable it.

Some people have run across the same problem, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7914).

Comment: This perfectly worked! I don't remember actually installing it, probably did at some point in my training when we used to deal with many DBMSs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just saved my precious time. Thanks a lot. Perhaps it was installed by Spring Boot Extension.

Comment: That fixed it. I completely forgot I'd accepted the prompt to install Dependency Analytics when doing a little Java work the other day.